# JavaScript: get values data from Destructuring of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this data set:

```
const data = {
    prop1: 'z',
    prop2: 'x',
    prop3: 'y',
    snippetItem_en: "abc",
    snippetItem_fr: "def",
    snippetCar_en: "123",
    snippetCar_fr: "456",
}
```

I take the translations out of it like this:

```
const {prop1, prop2, prop3, ...translations} = data;
```

But I would like to convert this received result in translations into such a result:

```
const carTranslations = {en: '123', fr: '456'};
const itemTranslations = {en: 'abc', fr: 'def'};
```

So far I have achieved this effect through such a petticoat, but I am convinced that it can be done better.

```
const carTranslations = {};
const itemTranslations = {};


  ['en', 'fr'].forEach((language) => {
    carTranslations[language] = translations[`snippetCar_${language}`];
    itemTranslations[language] = translations[`snippetItem_${language}`];
  });
```

Comment: It looks like it can be done better if translations were structured on level above, e.g. on backend side. Otherwise it will look like ad-hoc solution anyway. How do you get this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to implement a sorting algorithm. Destructuring is used to get the same named constants from your example code.

```js
const data = {
  prop1: 'z',
  prop2: 'x',
  prop3: 'y',
  snippetItem_en: "abc",
  snippetItem_fr: "def",
  snippetCar_en: "123",
  snippetCar_fr: "456",
}

const {
  prop1,
  prop2,
  prop3,
  ...translations
} = data;

const {
  carTranslations,
  itemTranslations
} = Object.entries(translations).reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
  const [phrase, lang] = key.replace('snippet', '').toLowerCase().split('_');
  result[phrase + 'Translations'] ??= {};
  result[phrase + 'Translations'][lang] = value;
  return result;
}, {});


console.log(carTranslations);
console.log(itemTranslations);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it more dynamic with a modified 'group-by'. Here using a regex with [named capturing groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#using_named_capturing_groups) to isolate the `category` and `language` and then grouping into an object keyed by `category`.

```js
const data = { prop1: 'z', prop2: 'x', prop3: 'y', snippetItem_en: "abc", snippetItem_fr: "def", snippetCar_en: "123", snippetCar_fr: "456", };

const { prop1, prop2, prop3, ...translations } = data;

const translationCategories = {};
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(translations)) {
  const { category, language } = key.match(/snippet(?<category>\w+)_(?<language>\w+)/).groups;
  const categoryKey = `${category.toLowerCase()}Translations`;

  translationCategories[categoryKey] ??= {};
  translationCategories[categoryKey][language] = value;
}

console.log(translationCategories);
```